# Error running query: STDDEV is an analytic function and must be accompanied by an OVER clause

Tags: google-bigquery

SELECT user, Lat, Long,stdlat,stdlong
FROM
(SELECT 
user, ROUND(locLatitude,2) AS Lat, ROUND(locLongitude,2) AS 
Long,STDDEV(locLatitude) as stdlat, STDDEV(locLongitude) as stdlong 
FROM [Table]
WHERE product='ABC'
AND YEAR(StartTime) =2016 
AND StartTime <= CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() 
AND STDDEV(locLatitude) <10 
AND STDDEV(locLongitude) <10 
GROUP BY 1,2,3) 
WHERE 
stdlat <=2 
AND stdlong <=2 
AND Lat NOT IN (0.0) 
AND Long NOT IN (0.0) 
GROUP BY 1,2,3,4,5

When I execute the above query I get an error saying "Error running query: STDDEV is an analytic function and must be accompanied by an OVER clause"

CAn someone help me understand What is wrong with my query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try below fix for inner SELECT

```
  SELECT
    user,
    ROUND(locLatitude,2) AS Lat,
    ROUND(locLongitude,2) AS Long,
    STDDEV(locLatitude) AS stdlat,
    STDDEV(locLongitude) AS stdlong
  FROM [Table]
  WHERE product='ABC'
    AND YEAR(StartTime) =2016
    AND StartTime <= CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()
  GROUP BY 1,2,3
  HAVING stdlat < 10
  AND stdlong < 10
```